# Reference range when column matches string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Budget spreadsheet. Column A contains categories, Row 1 contains paycheck dates, and each cell from B2:AE91 contains numeric values ("how much I spent on categoryX during paycheckY").

Named ranges:

- Column A - "Budget_LineItem"
- Row 1 - "Budget_PayPeriods"

On another tab, I have a list of specific categories called "Funds," where I want to track how much I've saved so far each paycheck toward the category by adding up the category's values each paycheck up until TODAY().

For example:
|   | A | B | C | D |
| - | - | - | - | - |
| 1 | **Fund** | **Balance** | Today: | =TODAY() |
| 2 | Auto Insurance | =SUMIF(Budget_PayPeriods,"<="&MAX($D$1:$D$2),Budget!F48:AE48) | Projected Date: | |

As you can see, I just have a static range for the "Auto Insurance" category: Budget!B48:AE48. This ***works,*** but I want a formula that looks up the adjacent value in column A against the Budget_LineItem range, and returns the row range from B:AE in the Budget spreadsheet.

Basically reads: "Go find how much I've saved/spent so far toward categoryX in the Budget tab, and add up all the values for each paycheck up through today."

I know I'm close, but I can't make INDEX, MATCH, or any of the LOOKUP functions do what I need. I just can't figure it out.

**EDIT:** Here's a link to an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L4mlMrRCWwDNPSiYHpmFiXU1zNOnga6gAziz_m2awKI/edit?usp=sharing
I also made a change to the OP formula in B2 as I realized it didn't work. I had tweaked it because my original formula had extra complexity and I was trying to KISS for this question. I changed it back to the more complex version so it works properly now.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: done, see OP edit

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: sorry @player0, should be fixed now

Answer (score 1):

delete  range B2:B and use this in B2:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(FILTER(Budget!B2:4, Budget!B1:1<=MAX(D1:D2))*1, 
 SEQUENCE(SUMPRODUCT((Budget!B1:1<=MAX(D1:D2))))^0))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 {Budget!A2:A4, MMULT(FILTER(Budget!B2:4, Budget!B1:1<=MAX(D1:D2))*1, 
 SEQUENCE(SUMPRODUCT((Budget!B1:1<=MAX(D1:D2))))^0)}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work, getting the following error: "FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 29." The 29 columns I believe are referring to the all columns including and to the left of the first pay period, Budget!B1:1. Which means I think your MMULT() is assuming there are an equal number of columns (pay periods) as there are rows (categories), which is not true.

Comment: Update: I changed my formula from "FILTER(Budget!F36:F91" to "FILTER(Budget!F36:91" and now it seems to have populated values for every category in the Budget tab, not just the categories listed in the Funds tab. But it does correctly add the sum for each category up until TODAY(), so we're making progress. How can I make it only return values when Budget tab categories match the Funds tab categories?

Comment: @Willman example you shared in your sheet is obviously insufficient and does not reflect the true structure of your dataset (next time make sure we are on the same page)

Comment: @Willman to match your categories you can use vlookup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGNPz.png